# A program that forces reconnection to a specific WiFi network

Tags: windows-10, wifi

Recently and some times in the past, I have encountered that **Windows 10 Home Version 1903 (OS Build 18362.267)** is simply unwilling to automatically reconnect to a home network when the said network is in range, or otherwise available.

This sometimes happens after a restart, router being down or after an update. It's is extremely annoying to me, as this is happening on a laptop I have in a completely different location than where I'm presently at, making it impossible to simply come by and turn it on.

So basically I'm looking for a third-party program/software, paid or otherwise, that is capable of force-reconnecting to the specified network, since you sometimes just can't rely on Windows at all